Unable to connect lead webhook - webhook.delivery.rejected
Description
I've been working on processing leads through our system and encountered an issue. I've enabled webhooks on my app, subscribed to leadgen, and provided my callback redirect URL. However, whenever I create a lead, it should be sent to my server, but when I track the status, it shows "failed" with the message "webhook.delivery.rejected."
I've looked in the logs of my application but the request is not entering my server at all. I'm trying to understand why this is happening and how to ensure my configuration is correct for receiving leads.
Previously, I completed the process manually by subscribing to each webhook with a seperate app, and it worked fine. Now, I want to programmatically do this using Facebook’s API and one app. Here's the request I'm using to subscribe to the webhook for leads:
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=leadgen&access_token={page_token}"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '{
"override_callback_uri": "https://api-development.recrubo.app/facebook/webhooks/{organization_id}",
"verify_token": "{verify_token}"
}'
Debugging
Here are my debugging steps so far: I've used the Facebook sharing debugger tool with my callback URL, which returns a 200 status. You can check the results here: Debugging Results..
I've used the Lead Ads RTU Debug Tool to send a test lead to our server but it isn't arriving at my server.
Question
Is there any place to see more error logging in the developer app?
Code
The perform method calls all subsequent calls .
It first fetches the user_id which is used to check what pages the user has given us access to.
It then fetches the page_access_tokens for all the accessible pages.
It then loops through the pages and subscribes to the webhooks.
 def perform
  @user_id = get_user_id
  @pages = get_page_access_tokens
  @pages.each do |page|
    @facebook.subscribe_to_webhook(page[:id], page[:token])
    token = @facebook.get_long_lived_access_token(page[:token])
    options = {
      ad_account_id: @ad_account_id
    }

    @access_token ||= @organization.access_tokens.create!(token: token, options: options, name: 'Meta', user_id: @user_id)
  end
  @access_token
end


def get_page_access_tokens(user_id, access_token)
  response = Faraday.get("#{ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API')}/#{user_id}/accounts") do |req|
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.params['access_token'] = access_token
  end

  raise "Unable to get page access token server responded with #{response.body} and status #{response.status}" unless response.success?

  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  page_data = data['data']
  page_data.map { |page| { id: page['id'], name: page['name'], token: page['access_token'] } }
end

def subscribe_to_webhook(page_id, page_token)
  response = Faraday.post("#{ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API')}/#{page_id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=leadgen") do |req|
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.params['access_token'] = page_token
    req.body = {
      override_callback_uri: "#{ENV.fetch('API_URL')}/facebook/webhooks/#{@organization['id']}",
      verify_token: {local_token}
    }.to_json
  end

  raise "Unable to subscribe to leadgen webhook server responded with #{response.body} and status #{response.status}" unless response.success?
  response
end

def get_user_id(access_token)
  response = Faraday.get("#{ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API')}/me") do |req|
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.params['fields'] = 'id'
    req.params['access_token'] = access_token
  end

  raise "Unable to get user id server responded with #{response.body} and status #{response.status}" unless response.success?
  JSON.parse(response.body)['id']
end

Edit 1
After the comment of CBroe we have looked further in to the subscription and have added validation for these subscriptions. We see the following data:

graph.facebook.com/v20.0{page_id}/subscribed_apps


graph.facebook.com/v20.0{app_id}/subscriptions




This got anything to do with it, maybe? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/: "It is possible to subscribe to more fields at the page level than the app level. However, only fields with subscriptions at both the page and app levels will get Webhooks. To make sure you are subscribed to the same fields at the app level, use the app subscriptions endpoint."

Hey Cbroe! Thanks for your reply! We've checked the subscriptions both on app & page level. We did this by calling these two routes:

https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{page_id}/subscribed_apps
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{app_id}/subscriptions

In both responses contained the lead_gen field in the subscriptions. The app contained multiple subscriptions that we use for messaging while the page only contains the lead_gen subscription. I'll add the responses to the issue!
